# Prevent Chrome from stripping url parameters

Tags: angular, google-chrome, web

I am working on an Angular 6 application and I would like to read the id of an item that resides in the url. For instance www.mywebsite.com/3, I am trying to retrieve 3. It works fine in IE but in Chrome it is redirecting to www.mywebsite.com/# therefore there is no way for me to retrieve the id (3 for the example url) which I rely upon to retrieve the item in the back end. Is there a workaround for this issue?
    Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to show some code. Namely, your routes array and the place where you either have a the `routerLink` or a `router.navigate` call

Comment: @JDillon522 how are you going to do that? Whatever I read from the router or Location from the Chrome browser does not return the id. It just gives me the main url.

Comment: *It works fine in IE but in Chrome it is redirecting to ...* - could you post the code with which you ''read'' the url params ?

Answer (score 1):

In TS

```
export class YourXPTOComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  }
}
```

in your route

```
  {
    path: 'yourPath/:id',
    component: YourXPTOComponent,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by adding an extra # to the URL. So if we have www.mysite.com/#/3the 3 will stay in the address bar in Chrome.